# Pass/inject object to adviced method in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, aop, spring-aop

Here is the situation. I have a starter which performs checks on every request. I have performed it by creating such an aspect:

```
    @Around("execution(* (@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *).*(..))")
    public Object check(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {

        CheckResponse checkResponse = client.check();
        if (checkResponse.getDate().before(new Date())) {
             throw new CheckException("message");
        }
   
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Everything worked fine until I needed to use this `CheckResponse` in my rest controller.
How can I get it inside there? I thought about creating request scoped beans inside my aspect and injecting it into controller with spring but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically. I guess another way can be using reflection but I am inclined to more elegant ways. Maybe you have any ideas?

P.S. The controller method has its own parameters such as @RequestParam, and using joinPoint.proceed() can override those parameters. I am trying to make this thing as much universal as possible.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140668/19979867) the solution

Comment: I have edited the post. I am not sure I can proceed with new arguments because controller has its own arguments which can be erased.

Comment: You have all the arguments in the controller available in `joinPoint` object. You can send the same parameters plus a new one. You will have to add a new parameter in the Controller though.